# Sorting of data from array list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a array list consisting of **data in the format of**

> 12 August 2011, 11 September 2011

I used my below code to do the sorting:

```
Array.Sort(fileNames, delegate(string first, string second)
{

  return DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(first), Convert.ToDateTime(second));
});
```

The result I get from the above code is

> 11 September 2011, 12 August 2011

after sorting

Comment: This works fine in .NET 4 / LINQPad -- I am on Windows 7 (not phone) and English locale (the locale matters). Might want to list the DateTime's that resulted from the Convert, they might not be as expected. (`Convert.ToDateTime(string)` tries really hard to "just work", which might not be the desired "working" result.)

Answer (score 2):

You say that your data is "an array list of strings" - do you mean

```
List<string>
```

or

```
string[]
```

?

It makes a little bit of a difference in the way you go about implementing the code.  Presuming you have an actual array, then the code is pretty straight forward, albeit not as clean as we would like:

```
private void SortButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = null;
    Array.Sort(items, delegate(string first, string second)
    {
        return DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(first), Convert.ToDateTime(second));
    });
    ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = items;
}
```

If, however, you're dealing with a List<string> called "items", then this approach won't work by itself.  You have to juggle around some stuff to make this happen:

```
private void SortButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = null;
    var arrayOfItems = items.ToArray<string>();
    Array.Sort(arrayOfItems, delegate(string first, string second)
    {
        return DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(first), Convert.ToDateTime(second));
    });
    items = new List<string>(arrayOfItems);
    ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = items;
}
```

Similar, but different :)  Since the sorting is happening in place, it actually just sorts the array and not the actual List<string> that we were using.

Now - note the clearing of the ItemsSource before and resetting after. I played with it for a bit, but couldn't get it to work properly without doing both of these steps.  I think this is a breakdown somewhere in the data binding infrastructure. I tried using a string[], List and ObservableCollection, but each time had to clear and reset the ItemsSource to get the ListBox to repaint.

Your comments about the Convert.ToDateTime() didn't seem to be a problem for me. I also tried DateTime.Parse() and that worked as well.  The problem turned out to be in the clearing and reassigning of the ListBox.ItemsSource.

Does anyone know why ListBox behaves this way? Is it something simple I'm just forgetting?